# Copy and rename a File inside a DefaultTask Class?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I want to duplicate all files from my `srcDir`which contain $$ in their name. If a file is for example:

```
x$$y.java
```

I want to create a copy of that file and name it `x$y.java`.

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

@InputDirectory File srcDir

@TaskAction
def task() {
  def srcFiles = project.files(project.fileTree(dir: srcDir)).getFiles()
  srcFiles.each { file ->  
        if (file.name.contains("\$\$")) {
           // TODO copy file and rename it to the same name with one dollar sign in the middle

        }
  }
}
}
```

**How can I copy and rename a file inside a custom task class?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@TaskAction
def task() {
   project.copy {
      from(project.fileTree(dir: srcDir).files) {
         include {
           it.file.name.contains('$$')
         }
      }
      into('somewhere')
      rename { name ->
         name.replace('$$', '$')
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @confile, have just updated it, it's even simpler now.